# Can I create pivot using perl?

Tags: excel, perl, pivot

I am generating Excel files with Perl using the use Excel::Writer::XLSX module. I put the data on a sheet. I want to automatically as I create the Excel file, also create a pivot table and chart with that data.  The pivot table and charts need to have filter, so I can select Month, Week, Status, Department. I have been searching for days with no result on how to do that.

If you know a better suitable option with other programming languages, like python, ruby or java. Please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Happy Holidays!

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~bdulfer/Data-Pivot-0.05/Pivot.pm http://search.cpan.org/~ruz/GDGraph-1.48/Graph.pm http://search.cpan.org/~nicolaw/RRD-Simple-1.44/lib/RRD/Simple.pm

Answer (score 2):

To my best knowledge none of the Perl modules supports pivot tables in Excel at the moment nativly.

There is two workaround: Create and setup the pivot (like a template) and the chart by hand then load your data and save a file in different name.

Create a pivot table using OLE, it is working only on windows. Starting point: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=651561

Regards,