# How to add pivot table with Excel::Writer::XLSX

Tags: excel, perl

Now I have a problem about how to add pivot table to Excel file(V2007) with Excel::Writer::XLSX. I have been seeking for the answer, but I couldn't find any one. Do you know it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create pivot using perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889282/can-i-create-pivot-using-perl)

Answer (score 0):

No. But if you check [TO DO](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.76/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#TO_DO) section of this module you'll find the answer:

> Pivot tables, maybe.

Comment: That comment was removed in this commit: https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/commit/42e5b370d39c7b2ddadfea59196d25958355c49e#diff-eadab63ec47ddd71df7d8ec225332c18L6747