# Write Pivot Table to Excel Workbook Range using XLSX Writer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of tables I would like to write to the same worksheet. The only other post similar to this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192393/how-to-add-pivot-table-with-excelwriterxlsx). I also looked [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.76/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#___top) but didn't see a solution.

I was hoping for a similar situation to SAS ODS Output codes that send `proc freq` results to an excel file. My thought was turning the table results into a new data frame and then stacking the output results to a worksheet.

```
pd.value_counts(df['name'])
df.groupby('name').aggregate({'Id': lambda x: x.unique()})
```

If I know the number of rows corresponding to the table, I should ideally know the appropriate range of cells to write to.

I am using:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

tableone = pd.value_counts(df['name'])
tabletwo = df.groupby('name').aggregate({'Id': lambda x: x.unique()})

worksheet.write('B2:C15', tableone)
worksheet.write('D2:E15', tabletwo)

workbook.close()
```

**EDIT: Include view of tableone**

TableOne:

```
  Name           |        Freq
    A                       5
    B                       1
    C                       6
    D                       11
```

Comment: I just recently learned about this module it is great, what problem are you having?  I generally loop over my data (tableone) and write a cell at a time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

tableone = pd.value_counts(df['name'])
tabletwo = df.groupby('name').aggregate({'Id': lambda x: x.unique()})


col = 1, row = 1 #This is cell b2
for value in tableone:
    if col == 16:
        row += 1
        col = 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, value)
    col += 1

col = 3, row = 1 #This is cell d2
for value in tabletwo:
    if col == 16:
        row += 1
        col = 1
    worksheet.write(row,col,value)
    col += 1
```

Comment: So, I am very new, but when I add this code, I get an SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: What sort of structure do tableone and tabletwo have?  You may need to modify the loop appropriately.  I can't seem to find a method in the docs for writing multiple values in one go, so it does seem you will need to loop and write a cell at a time.  But you can use numerical indices instead of the alphanumeric excel default; note they do start at 0.

Comment: Edit above to show table structure. I am trying to just output basic frequency lists.

Comment: Oh forgive me I forgot to mention the other write functions, I think you are trying to use write to write a number, when the function should be write_number.  But if you convert the number to a string you can use write as in my example (str(value)))